# Substituting argument value in bash

Tags: bash

I'm unable to substitute the argument value(s) in the bash command as below:

```
# echo $int1
{"id":"74953939-fd20-4472-8aaa-067e6f4c4106"}
# echo $int2
{"id":"5ef4664d-3600-4df9-a6a9-01ffb0f49422"}
# echo $int3
{"id":"6dc95c01-742e-4225-8298-e5750fe67f27"}

# set -x
# data set net-agent interfaces '["$int1", "$int2", "$int3"]'
+ data set net-agent interfaces '["$int1", "$int2", "$int3"]'
```

Any idea on why the values are not being substituted?

Thanks!

Comment: probably because you are using single quotes, so that the variables are not expanded. Try `data set ... "['$int1',...`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help.

Comment: that does help... I guess you have other problems but... you haven't even described what you want.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: You need to make it clear what you're trying to do and why the suggestions you have been provided don't help.

Comment: The suggestion I received from @fedorqui resulted in the same result - the values were not being substituted. That was the issue I was interested in get resolved. Not sure why the question was down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the argument to the command should be valid JSON, in which case you should remove the double quotes from around each variable and wrap the entire string in double quotes so variables are expanded:

```
data set net-agent interfaces "[$int1, $int2, $int3]"
```

Using `set -x`, this produces:

```
$ data set net-agent interfaces "[$int1, $int2, $int3]"
+ data set net-agent interfaces '[{"id":"74953939-fd20-4472-8aaa-067e6f4c4106"}, {"id":"5ef4664d-3600-4df9-a6a9-01ffb0f49422"}, {"id":"6dc95c01-742e-4225-8298-e5750fe67f27"}]'
```